# NetSuite Assembly Build error, "The total inventory detail quantity must be...", what is causing this?

Tags: version-control, netsuite

Attempting to declare production of an assembly using the assembly build.  As far as I can tell we have enough item inventory to assign the lots-bins-item-quantities to everything in the BOM.   Cannot declare.  Usually get an error about a particular item.  Have seen that item be different on different attempts.  Have looked at that item and appears we have enough.  I've even decremented the BOM blow out to a lower quantity to assign inventory detail that matches.

I do notice that the "Buildable" quantity populates as about a half unit less than the build quantity I enter.  This matches the "buildable" quantity shown on the WO.   I don't know if these two issues are related.  I can't tell how it's coming up with the buildable number or the constraint from matching the WO quantity.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate if this is via SuiteScript, or via the user interface, so I'll assume this is the client interface.

The Builable figure is based on the minimum quantity of each component committed to the work order (if committment is enabled). Given that you are seeing a .5 less than the quantity required, then this item is buildable to a degree, but requires more component stock.

The message you are seeing on the assembly build can be because :

1. The quantity entered on one or more components doesn't match the bin location quantities e.g 7 are required but only 5 have been provided in bins ; and/or;
2. One or more items are serialised or lot controlled, and the inventory detail has not been completed to include this information. e.g. 5 are required, but the lot numbers XX and YY are used to a quantity of 4; and/or
3. The item being built is serialised or lot controlled, and the lot/serial reference of the built assembly has not been entered, e.g the serial number 5 are being built and serial numbers 123, 124, 125, 126 & 127 should be provided to create the serialised assembly.

See  [SuiteAnswer 28169](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/28169/kw/buildable) and [SuiteAnswer 28170](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/28170/kw/buildable) for information on creating a build of serial & lot assemblies.

Comment: Thank you Simon.  Yes client interface.

For #1 ->  Is there a way to see thru the interface which component is short?
For #2 ->  Can you clarify that a bit more?     Is this something like the component can only be used in certain multiples?
For my specific situation I can rule out #3.

Thank you these three possibilities are more clarity than we have received from NetSuite Tem.

Comment: Both #1 & #2 are managed throught the inventory detail icon on each row of components. It looks like a packing box with either a green tick or blue downward-pointing arrow (i.e. it needs something putting in). If you are already performing item receipts and fulfillments then it's the same icon.